# how to get ajax return id in hidden variable....on request page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to get last insert id from controller to ajax success function......
I want to customize product and when user press add to cart ajax is executed and design is going to insert on database....
And after inserting in database i m getting last insert id.....on insert...
but need last insert id....when user press on add to cart button in hidden field...
here is my Ajax code.

```
$('#store').click(function(){

    $.ajax({                                      
      type: "POST",              
      url: ajax_url_store,       
      data: {action: 'store', views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct()) },
      success: function(data) {
                            if(parseInt(data) > 0) {
                            //successfully added..here i am getting last insert id...
                            // and i want to pass that in hidden variable.....
                            // on view page.....
                                }
                                else {
                                       document.getElementById('succes-message').innerHTML = 'You Design has not Been                                                                                                   Saved';             
                                }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            //alert('some error has occured...');
                        },
                        start: function() {
                            //alert('ajax has been started...');    
                        }
          });
});
```

my CI controller

```
public function saveData(){
            if($this->input->post('action') == 'store') {
                $views = $this->input->post('views');
                $id = $this->product_model->save($views);
                $data = array('cust_id'=>$id); 
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);    
                if($id !=''){
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($id);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->insert_id() returns the last id.

Answer (score 0):

After your insertion operation in model, use following code

> $this->db->insert_id();

this will give you `id` where last insert done.

[Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)